# SSH command gets terminated while compressing a directory

Tags: compression, gzip, tar

I am compressing a big directory about 50GB containing files and folder using putty SSH COMMAND LINE.i am using this command:

```
tar czspf file.tar.gz directory/
```

it starts work fine, but after some time it gets terminated with single word message "Terminated" and compression stopped near about 16GB of tar archive.

Is there any way to escape from terminated error or how to deal this problem, or any other method to make a tar of directory avoiding the terminate error.Thanks

Comment: You are more likely to get a good answer to this question if you ask it on Unix.StackExchange.com or SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you conflict with some kind of file size limit. Not all file system supports very big files. In this case you could pipe the output of the tar into a split command like this:
tar czsp directory/|split -b4G fileprefix-